# Illegal pattern character with maven-jaxb2-plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-jaxb2-plugin

I'm new of maven this is the first time that I'm using maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate  java classes from a .xsd schema.

This is my pom.xml:

```
 <properties>
    <java.source.version>1.6</java.source.version>
    <java.target.version>1.6</java.target.version>
 </properties>
 <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                <target>${java.target.version}</target>
            </configuration>

        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/schema</schemaDirectory>
                <schemaIncludes>
                    <include>mySchema.xsd</include>
                </schemaIncludes>
                <generatePackage>it.mycompany.jaxb2</generatePackage>
                <readOnly>true</readOnly>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>    
<dependencies>
    <!-- A few dependiences -->
</dependencies>
```

The trouble is that when i try to run

> mvn install

i get the following error

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.8.3:generate failed: Illegal pattern character 'g'
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:115)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
... 20 more
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern character 'g'
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.compile(SimpleDateFormat.java:768)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.initialize(SimpleDateFormat.java:575)
at java.text.SimpleDateFormat.<init>(SimpleDateFormat.java:500)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.Options.getPrologComment(Options.java:937)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.addon.episode.PluginImpl.run(PluginImpl.java:177)
at com.sun.tools.xjc.model.Model.generateCode(Model.java:294)
at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.generateCode(XJC22Mojo.java:70)
at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:45)
at org.jvnet.mjiip.v_2_2.XJC22Mojo.doExecute(XJC22Mojo.java:29)
at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.doExecute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:318)
at org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2.RawXJC2Mojo.execute(RawXJC2Mojo.java:160)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:106)
... 21 more
```

Maven is configured in this way:

> mvn --version Maven home: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\apache-maven-3.1.1\bin.. Java version: 1.6.0_45, vendor: Sun
>   Microsystems Inc. Java home: C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\jre Default locale: it_IT, platform encoding:
>   Cp1252 OS name: "windows 8", version: "6.2", arch: "x86", family:
>   "windows"

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: As the stacktrace says, you have a problem with a date format defined somewhere -- and not in your pom.xml. In the XSD, maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that  maven-jaxb2-plugin of default use the version 2.2.6 of jaxb-xjc, this version has some problem with

> Default locale: it_IT

but works only with a US Locale. Then i added the following dependence on my pom

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-xjc</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.5</version>
  </dependency>
```

and now everything works.